# C# CSearch Tuple list with wildcards

Tags: c#, list, wildcard, tuples

I have a list like this:

```
List<Tuple<int, int, int>> list = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
```

Now I need to remove all the Tuple's in the list with a certain Item1 and Item3, but it doesn't matter what Item2 is.

I have no clue how to acchief this.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.RemoveAll(t => t.Item1 == cond1 && t.Item3 == cond3);
```

Comment: did you mean what I had in there before? yes, I mixed up the syntax with some other RemoveAll method.